# Automatically request permission to access current location on load

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

Can we request user's permission to access their current location every time when Google map loads? I would like to show the share location permission for every request.

Answer (score 0):

If you attempt to use it, the browser will either ask for permission to use it, or deny the request without asking (if the user has set that) or possibly allow it without asking (if the user has set that). You can't override the browser behaviour.